# Obtain list of unique tokens and bigrams sorted by frequency counting across multiple documents in JSON file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have several thousands of txt files that I processed removing stopwords, punctuation, lemmatizing, etc. Right now I'm trying to obtain a list, sorted by frequency, of unique tokens and unique bi-grams across all my txt files. I managed to do it for each file obtaining a JSON file that is structured like this:

```
{
   “file_name1”: {
       “magazine”: “magazine_name”,
       “country”: “country_of_origin”,
       “year”: “year_of_publication”,
       “tokens”: [“token1”, “token2”],
       “bigramFreqs": {“token1 token2”: freq, “token2 token3”: freq},
       "tokenFreqs": {“token1: freq”, “token2”: freq}
   }

   “file_name2”: {
       “magazine”: “magazine_name”,
       “country”: “country_of_origin”,
       “year”: “year_of_publication”,
       “tokens”: [“token1”, “token2”],
       “bigramFreqs": {“token1 token2”: freq, “token2 token3”: freq},
       "tokenFreqs": {“token1: freq”, “token2”: freq}
   }
}
```

I would like to obtain a separate file (ideally a spreadsheet) structured like this. I have over 7000 documents and they're all very long, so it's possible that a csv file would run into its row limit. Alternatively, another JSON file would be ok, but I don't know how to loop across the files saved in my JSON output to get an overall list of unique tokens and bigrams with their frequencies.

| Unique tokens | Token frequency | Unique bigrams | Bigram frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Token 1 | 670 | united states | 380 |
| Token 2 | 495 | european union | 218 |

Edit:
I managed to merge the data, count how many times each unique token/bigram appears, and save the output in a JSON file with the following solution. I still struggle to actually sort tokens by frequency and I'm unsure about the most appropriate format to save the output to make it easily accessible.

```
with open("input/output.json", "r") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

token_list = []
for key in data:
    sub_list = data[key]["tokens"]
    token_list.append(sub_list)

import itertools
temp_t = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(token_list))

from collections import Counter
merged_tokens = Counter(temp_t)

file_path = "input/merged_tokens.json"
with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(merged_tokens, file)
```